# Replace content from file using sed command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Hi I want to replace below line from my file using sed command.

> ) ENGINE=TokuDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 `compression`='tokudb_zlib';

I want to Replace a line starting with  ) ENGINE and replace that complete line with `;`

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

Done With following Command

```
sed "s/) ENGINE.*/);/g" abc.sql > abc1.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
sed -i 's/)\sENGINE.*/;/g' path_to_your_file
```